# What exactly do I have to do to finish the pumpkin soup quest?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I'm playing LoZ Skyward Sword and I'm supposed to bring Eagus pumpkin soup which I did (and I did it and got back to pumpkin landing all under 5 minutes) and he still tells me that he has no idea what he wants me to do for him next. I don't know what to do because I've looked at so many other sources and they all just said "Bring it in less than 5 minutes" which I did so I don't know. I keep spending my rupees on more and more pumpkin soup and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. When I give Eagus his pumpkin soup under 5 minutes he says,

"Hey...did you happen to bring more piping-hot pumpkin soup?! It looks sooo good... Oh! For me?! I mean, sorry for just assuming it was for me... Well, in that case, I'll help myself! Yeah! That hits the spot! I tell you, morning, noon, or night, nothing satisfies like Pumm's pumpkin soup! Thank you, Link! Here's a little token my appreciation"

Then he just gives me 20 rupees which seems like I did the right thing then i just go back and he still doesn't know what i have to do next.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have finished the pumpkin soup delivery quest. What's "next" will be a different quest that won't unlock until you hit a certain point in the story. I believe the "pay for the chandelier" chain of sidequests has the following triggers:

- Bust the old chandelier in the Lumpy Pumpkin.
- Complete the second dungeon.
- Successfully use the Goddess Harp to unlock an area, then proceed to gain the ability to use it for a second area. (not totally sure where this trigger is, but the harp is mandatory)